# Mongoengine - Hierarchical view of list field of referrence fields

Tags: python, mongoengine, rbac

**Context:**
I have a mongoDB of Dynamic documents that include a ListField of ReferrenceField(s). For example:

```
    object A: {name: 'string', sub_object: [object B: {name: 'string'}]}
```

**Goal:** Find a query to retrieve an hierarchical view of object A with all of its sub objects' names.

**Question:** What would be the best MongoDB-way to achieve this goal? As of now, I can get the ID of the sub objects, however, for front end convenience, the names are needed. I also feel like that the current model structure is wrong and there is a better way to achieve this..

PS. *It's an RBAC model, if it helps, thus why I can't share more information regarding the structure.*